# Is There A Way To Upgrade to OpenCL 2.0?

Tags: opencl

There is a feature in OpenCL 2.0 that I would like to use.

I dual boot Ubuntu and Mac OS (Graphics: GTX 670 + HD Graphics 4600).  Is it possible to install OpenCL 2.0?

This may be a dumb question - from what I have read, it seems like 2.0-compatible drivers may not be written yet?  And also possibly my hardware will not support the new spec?

Basically, when will OpenCL 2.0 be easy/available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no OpenCL 2.0 drivers yet. The specification just became final yesterday. I don't believe any public statements have been made yet about when drivers will become available, and for what hardware. You'll have to wait for whatever fun new feature you wanted. Better yet, let your favorite vendors know that you'd like them to support OpenCL 2.0!

Comment: Update: AMD and Intel have now both released OpenCL 2.0 drivers!

Answer (score 6):

You mentioned you have an NVidia GTX 670; you should note that NVidia's drivers only support **OpenCL 1.1**, not 1.2.

NVidia have(*) refrained over the past several years from updating their drivers to support the newer OpenCL standard, even though the hardware obviously supports it and CUDA has all the relevant functionality... so don't expect 2.0 to happen so soon on your hardware.

(*) - Due to being Evil™.

Comment: Yep. If OpenCL 1.2 is not coming (and it clearly isn't), there isn't a  snowball's chance in hell NVidia is going to support 2.0. Only when CUDA dies will they finally make the move (if OpenCL is still around by then).

Comment: CUDA is not dying anytime soon; in fact, the CUDA approach - of compiling kernels at host code compile time, with support of joint headers, C++ constructs (e.g. templates, soo also function pointers) - is quite attractive, regardless of its being a one-vendor approach.

Comment: I do not deny CUDA being technologically superior to OpenCL. But it's not hard to be when you only have to support one architecture and you get to control that too (and of course a lot of projects do not require compatibility). We'll see how it evolves but I certainly hope a truly portable solution will emerge, and I strongly dislike how NVidia is acting like CUDA and OpenCL can't coexist and feels the need to try to kill an open source standard for its own benefit (the whole point of OpenCL is that it *is supposed* to run everywhere, and NVidia is defeating that goal on purpose)

Comment: @Thomas: I completely agree. I wish NVidia could be made to properly support OpenCL and integrate CUDA capabilities into it, or barring their good will, that AMD gets its act together and releases better, more stable OpenCL drivers and profiling tools.

Comment: What we need is to have the vendors and Khronos opensource OpenCL  so the community can provide OpenCL 1.2 on  NVidia hardware.

Comment: @TimChild: There's nothing _to_ open-source. OpenCL is an API standard. NVidia's or AMD's, or Intel's OpenCL implementations are just that - and the Khronos group has no access to their sources. However, FOSS _reference_ implementations would be nice; as would be requiring members to provide timely compliant impl's, and maybe even to open-source them to some degree.

Comment: Khronos has  an OpenCL conformance suite and there are  a set of standard OpenCL  headers that are used by all the vendors  as a basis for their implemntations. So that a  starting point.

Comment: @TimChild: Your comment sounds like an independent answer... suggest you make it one...

Answer (score 1):

There is some support for OpenCL in Clang 3.0 and from the LLVM organisation.

See the CLang 3.0 release notes

http://llvm.org/releases/3.0/docs/ClangReleaseNotes.html

Here's an LLVM presentation on OpenCL

http://llvm.org/devmtg/2009-10/OpenCLWithLLVM.pdf

Here's another Stackoveflow answer on Clang 3.0 for OpenCL

[How to use clang to compile OpenCL to ptx code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795114/how-to-use-clang-to-compile-opencl-to-ptx-code)

So there are some good folks working on an open source  version of OpenCL that compiles to PTX for NVida cards. Not having used it  and not being familiar with these efforts, I can't say if there are plans or when when they can get to the OpenCL 2.0 spec.