# Unresolved extern when compiling OpenCL to PTX using Clang?

Tags: clang, opencl, llvm-clang

I'm following the instructions on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21430910/759705) but when I try to run the resulting PTX file I get the follow error in clBuild

```
ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function 'get_group_id'
```

In the PTX file I have the following for every OpenCL function call I use

```
.func  (.param .b64 func_retval0) get_group_id
(
        .param .b32 get_group_id_param_0
)
;
```

The above isn't present in the PTX files created by the OpenCL runtime when I provide it with a CL file. Instead it has the proper special register.

Following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16810781/759705) (links against a different libclc library) gives me a segmentation fault during the LLVM IR to PTX compilation with the following error:

```
fatal error: error in backend: Cannot cast between two non-generic address spaces
```

Are those instructions still valid? Is there something else I should be doing?

I'm using the latest version of libclc, Clang 3.7, and Nvidia driver 352.39

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that llvm does not provide an OpenCL device code library. llvm however provides the intrinsics for getting the IDs of a GPU thread. Now you have to write your own implantations of `get_global_id` etc. using clang's builtins and compile it to llvm bitcode with the nvptx target. Before you lower your IR to PTX you use `llvm-link` to link your device library with your compiled OpenCL module and that's it.

A example how you would write such a function:

```
#define __ptx_mad(a,b,c) ((a)*(b)+(c))

__attribute__((always_inline)) unsigned int get_global_id(unsigned int dimindx) { 
  switch (dimindx) { 
    case 0: return __ptx_mad(__nvvm_read_ptx_sreg_ntid_x(), __nvvm_read_ptx_sreg_ctaid_x(), __nvvm_read_ptx_sreg_tid_x()); 
    case 1: return __ptx_mad(__nvvm_read_ptx_sreg_ntid_y(), __nvvm_read_ptx_sreg_ctaid_y(), __nvvm_read_ptx_sreg_tid_y()); 
    case 2: return __ptx_mad(__nvvm_read_ptx_sreg_ntid_z(), __nvvm_read_ptx_sreg_ctaid_z(), __nvvm_read_ptx_sreg_tid_z()); 
    default: return 0; 
  } 
}
```